# Slide down ListView item hidden content

Tags: android, visibility

I have this list with some hidden TextView.

When click on a item, I want to slide down smoothly and show the hidden content, and if click again, slide up.

How is that possible?

Hidden and not hidden:

[image: Image here]

Comment: An what have you tried? Stackoverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).

Expandable ListView bydefault has two levels. First is called the "Group View" and the second level is called the "Child View". You can simply achieve by making use of the Custom Adapter sample from the very first link I have provided.

here are few links which will get you started,

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html

http://about-android.blogspot.in/2010/04/steps-to-implement-expandablelistview.html

http://www.techienjoy.com/android-expandable-list-dynamically-created-example.php

To make only child expanded at a particular time, add this,

```
explist.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {


        for(int i=0; i<myExpAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
            if(i != groupPosition) {
                explist.collapseGroup(i);
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

ExpandableListView solves your problem functionally wise.

However if you want to have the smooth animation i recommend using a library I created myself.

https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView

It works with a normal ListView! And it got smooth animation.